# content_tag formatting to entities?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I use content_tag, my tags get converted to their HTML entity equivalent. The code I use is

The view renders

```
Hello This is a <strong>test</strong>
```

When I'd like it to render

Hello This is a **test**

The content format of the database is `text`, which may or may not affect the output, since there are newlines and return carriages within the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tell Rails the content is safe. Two options:

- `your_content.html_safe`
- `<%=raw your_content %>`